# Use Middleman liquid template and Localization

Tags: middleman

I was wondering if anyone has figured out a way to use the Liquid template language in Middleman, but still use Localization.

I've tried replacing:

```
<%= I18n.t(:hello) %>
```

With:

```
{{ 'hello' | t }}
```

or

```
{{ 'hello' | I18n.t }}
```

But can't seem to get it working. Anyone got advice for me?

Thanks!